# Assign a map in session attribute to a map object in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session

I am setting map in `session.setAttribute` as year(key) and models (value).

```
session.setAttribute(Model_By_year, map);
```

Now, in my JSP user will select a year and based on that year I need to display model - the mapping of which is in my map.

I want to use JavaScript for the same and on the year drop down in my JavaScript I am using `onchange="ModelByYear"` function.

Now the question is:

In js (ModelByYear() function) how can I set the value of model drop down based on the year selected?

Comment: Post your jsp page where you are displaying the map ?

Comment: <td>Model</td>
     <td>
      <html:select property="modelId">
      
       <html:options collection=
         "<%=GlobalValues.LIST_MODEL %>"
         property="id" labelProperty="value" />
      </html:select>
     </td>